# Deleting items from the array of objects

Tags: string, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a document that looks like:

```
{
  _id: "....",
  hostname: "mysite.com",
  text: [
    {
        source: "this is text. this is some pattern",
        ...
    },
    {
        source: "....",
        ...
     }
  ]
}
```

and I am trying to delete the items from the `text` array which match a specific condition in my query given as:

```
db.getCollection('TM').updateMany(
  {hostname: "mysite.com"},
  {
    $pull: {
            "text.source": /this is some pattern/
    }
  },
  { multi: true }
)
```

Here I want to delete all the items from the array where the value inside `source` matches `this is some pattern`. When I execute this query, it gives an error saying: `Cannot use the part (source) of (text.source) to traverse the element` with error code `28`.

What is the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> *it gives an error saying: Cannot use the part (source) of (text.source) to traverse the element with error code 28.*

Incorrect syntax of `$pull` for update methods,

Corrected syntax, and You can use `$regex` to find document by specific pattern,

- `"text.source"` the condition in filter part will filter main documents, it is optional
- `text: { source:` will filter sub documents and pull elements

```
db.getCollection('TM').updateMany(
  {
    hostname: "mysite.com",
    "text.source": { $regex: "this is some pattern" }
  },
  {
    $pull: {
      text: { source: { $regex: "this is some pattern" } }
    }
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/16PYORD1U0E)

Comment: Why do we need `text.source` twice? Could you help me understand this?

Comment: the query part is for filter main documents, and in update to filter from array element and pull it,  it will work if you don't specify in query part but it will still search in all documents when there is no matching string.

Comment: Got it. It removes the complete index right, not just the source part?

Comment: Also why do you have `text.source` in the filter part and `text:{source:` in the pull part? Does it create a difference?

Comment: yes it will remove complete element/index, you can test adding more fields.

Comment: and why do you write `text.source` differently in the pull operation?

Comment: i have added explanation in answer. let me know if you have any confusion.

Comment: can't we write `"text.source": { $regex: "this is some pattern" }` in the filter part as `text: { source: { $regex: "this is some pattern" } }`?

Comment: no, because `text: { source: { ` this in filter part will search whole `text` object, if there is any another field in `text` then your condition will fail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232264/discussion-between-amanda-and-turivishal).

Comment: I did not understand your last comment. What is the difference between the 2 syntaxes?

Comment: @Amanda no you can't use, i already explained you in answer, `filter` => you can use `"text.source"`, when you use `text: { source: ` this will search an object in your document but your having array, `update` => you can use `text: { source:`, when you use `"text.source"` it will throw error because its not valid syntax.

Comment: For more details you can read [how to query in embedded document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/) and [$pull condition in update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/).